# Ubuntu 17.10 can not play music by bluetooth devices

Tags: bluetooth

I'm using a bluetooth adapter to use my bluetooth headset as an output. But if i set the bluetooth device as an output device, no thing happened when I click the `Test Speakers` button.

The log shows:
`tail /var/log/syslog`:

```
Nov 15 10:12:57 shareginepc pulseaudio[1368]: [pulseaudio] backend-
native.c: connect(): Function not implemented
Nov 15 10:12:59 shareginepc gnome-control-c[2961]: Can't find the 
active output from the UI
```

What should I do to fix the problem?
Thank you for you attention, If you need more information, please tell me immediately.